# How can I format a phone number in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a `text_field_tag` where a user enters a phone number. I need to reformat the phone number after a user has entered it such as: `(XXX) XXX XXXX`. I create a java script where it will do it for me but how can I add it to this ruby line code ?

javascript method ------>   formatNumber(number)

```
<%= text_field_tag :mobile_number, '', :class => 'email-address' %>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using Rails, it's easier to use the built-in [#number_to_phone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_phone) helper instead of custom Javascript.

Comment: thanks, how can I call number_to_phone inside the tag ?                                     <%= text_field_tag :mobile_number, '', :class => 'email-address' %>

Comment: If you want to format it in the browser (on the form itself) you ARE going to need to use javascript. If you want to format it after the form has been sent (to store in the database, for example), then you can use number_to_phone

Comment: The answer pointed me to what I really wanted, which was not a helper for a view, but the original method. It's `ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_phone(number, options)`. Just look at the source from the link.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to use ruby variables and methods in javascript.
1) Use it in a .js.erb (usually used for rendering ajax method)
2) Probably your case, kind of ugly, but you can inline your javascript on your html.erb view